# Spectrum of this block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, block-matrices

Consider the following block matrix

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}  B & T\\ T & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

where all submatrices are square and

- matrix $B = \mbox{diag}\left(b_1 ,0,0,\dots,0,b_n \right)$ with $b_1, b_n > 0$.
- matrix $T$ is self-adjoint and positive semidefinite.

What can one say about the lowest eigenvalue of this matrix $A$? In particular, how does it depend on the spectrum of $T$ and the entries of $B$? Are there any known results?

Comment: $A$ may have negative eigenvalues, you want the smallest in absolute value or the most negative one?

Comment: the lowest one (which may be negative)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lambda_\max$ is the greatest eigenvalue of $T$, the least eigenvalue of $A$ is between $-\lambda_\max$ and $\max(b_1, b_n) - \lambda_\max$.

Comment: thank you, however do you mind briefly explaining how you get this?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{0 & T\cr T & 0\cr}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ and $-T$.  You're adding a positive semidefinite matrix.  Use the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).